efi stub warning: failed to measure data for event 1: 0*0000000000b
I updated Ubuntu from 23.10 and now I'm stuck on the Ubuntu Loading screen. I don't even get to the enter password screen and getting this warning on start efi stub warning: failed to measure data for event 1: 0*0000000000b.
I tried disabling "Enable Secure Boot" option and also tried Resetting Security in BIOS but that didn't work either. How to resolve this issue?

With UEFI Secure boot off, does it eventually boot? Other posts say this is just a warning and system should boot.  Can you get to grub menu?

@oldfred I can go past the Grub Menu but it doesn't show the Enter Password Screen!

At grub menu can you boot recovery mode or second entry? What video card/chip? What brand/model system? Recovery mode removes quiet splash and adds nomodeset to linux line in grub menu. You will see boot process. If it stops, often not last line posted but several over that line is issue. These lines are also in log file.

@oldfred Boot recovery mode also not helping! I'm using a Dell XPS 13 9310 and using Ubuntu as a dual boot.

I cannot get to your site. Many also do not like to click on unknown sites for security reasons. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/  Dell XPS 13 9310 Intel Xe Graphics' Incredible Performance Uplift From OpenCL
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=1185g7-windows10-ubuntu&num=1
